# Как импортровать контроллера в другой проект?

Tags: swift, xcode, objective-c

Как можно добавить классы контроллера в другой проект, чтобы он их видел?

Я перекидываю папку с контроллерами в другой проект, в другом проекте контроллеры не видят их. Как это исправить??
Пишет ошибку:

```
use of unresolved identifier
```

Comment: У вас вью контролеры на сториборде не видят классы, которые для них в swift файлах? Правильно я понял?

Comment: @NSA-bot, Ну почти, если я правильно понял ваш вопрос. Я положил из второго проекта контроллера в первый проект. И пытаюсь вызвать их из контроллера в первом проекте. И он их не видит